# User events on Calendar not updating after log out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I have an appointments application with multiple users who can multiple appointments. I display this on FullCalendar.

However, I'm having a problem. I want the User logged in to see their events and not others. This works when I close the application completely but if I log out and want to login as another user, I see the other users appointments.

I tried using re fetch events with FullCalendar then I looked at the `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` within my DAL class.

Here's my controller method:

```
public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        string username = Membership.GetUser().UserName;

        var getAdmin = (from a in db.Admins
                        where username == a.AdminUsername
                        select a.AdministrationId).SingleOrDefault();

        var events = (from a in db.Appointments
                      where getAdmin == a.AdministrationId
                      select a).ToList();

        return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

    }
```

And FullCalendar:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var events = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Appointments/GetEvents",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    events.push({
                        details: v.DetailsOfAppointment,
                        date: moment(v.DateOfAppointment),
                        room: v.RoomType,
                        confirmed: v.Confirmed,
                        colour: v.ThemeColour,
                        church: v.Church.Name,
                        parishAdminName: v.Admins.AdministratorName,
                        parishAdminUser: v.Admins.AdminUsername,
                        parishAdminId: v.Admins.AdministratorId,
                        fee: v.Fee,
                        id: v.AppointmentId
                    });

                })
                 GenerateCalender(events);   
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("failed");
                console.log(error);
            }
        })

        function GenerateCalender(events) {
            $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
            $('#calender').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 500,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: events.ThemeColour,
                events: events,
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    if (event.fee == null) {
                        if (event.confirmed == false) {
                            element.css('background-color', '#FF0000');
                            element.css('border-color', '#FF0000');
                        }
                        else {
                            element.css('background-color', '#008000');
                            element.css('border-color', '#008000');
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        element.css('background-color', '#0000FF');
                        element.css('border-color', '#0000FF');

                    }
                },
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    $('#myModal #details').text(calEvent.details);
                    var $details = $('<div/>');

                    if (calEvent.fee != null) {
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Date of Ceremony : </b>' + calEvent.date.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    }
                    else {
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Date of Appointment : </b>' + calEvent.date.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    }
                    if (calEvent.end != null) {
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    }
                    $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Details : </b>' + calEvent.details));
                    $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Church Name : </b>' + calEvent.church));
                    if (calEvent.fee == null) {
                        if (calEvent.room != null) {
                            $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Room : </b>' + calEvent.room));
                        }
                        else {
                            $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Room Not Confirmed'));
                        }
                    }


                    $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Parish Admin : </b>' + calEvent.parishAdminName));
                    if (calEvent.confirmed == true)
                    {
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Status : Confirmed </b>'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Status : Not Confirmed </b>'));
                    }
                    $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($details);

                    $('#myModal').modal();
                }

            })
        }
    })
</script>
```

}

Comment: Yes I am, forgot to include that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON payload is likely being cached by the browser.

To stop this, add this attribute above `GetEvents`:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*", Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
```

to disable caching.